# Xamarin GridView customGrid itemClick doesn't work

Tags: android, gridview, xamarin

Hi I am trying to work with gridview for my app(Xamarin Android). But there is something wrong or i misunderstand.

I write this in activity .

```
gridView.Adapter = new CustomGrid(this,jobRes);
```

And create new class extended from BaseAdapter

```
public class CustomGrid : BaseAdapter
```

Everything works and i am able to show items in screen as i expected. But the problem is i cannot implement click event.

In activity ;

```
 gridView.ItemClick += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs> (OnGridView_ItemClicked);
```

Or

```
gridView.ItemClick += (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) => {
```

Never trigger. I'd like to show new activity after someone click on an item. If i try to implement this on CustomGrid class then it works. But this time i am not able to reach StartActivity because that class is not extended from Activity.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I'm may be having a similar problem.

Comment: As far as I remember you need to implement click activity not for grid but for grid items.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.

Comment: Do you have any click event in CustomGrid  ?